# Selected notification sound overwritten by default

Tags: sms, notifications, handcent-sms

How do you make sure your selected notification sound (selected by any App) is not overwritten by the default? No matter how I try, and test the sound within the app (Handcent SMS) successfully, the selected sound is overwritten by the Subtle System Ringtone. Thanks!

Comment: What app?  Is the setting actually changed, or just ignored?  I think this is a probably a problem with the app not using its own setting, rather than an Android problem.

Comment: I use Handcent to set the notification. Handcent also gives you the option to test it within the app as well. As a double check, I go into the App - Settings>Sound>Notification Sound and the desired notification is properly indicated.

Comment: Hmm.  Normally I would think the app is erroneously ignoring the setting when it does "real" notifications, rather than tests, but now I'm wondering if it might be because it's for SMS.  The system might be notifying on SMS and drowning out the Handcent notification, or something similar.

Comment: Maybe try turning off notifications in the system Messages app, if you can?  Or changing them to the sound you want.

Comment: thanks for shedding light to this. i checked the settings under the default program, Messages, and there was the problem. notification was set to subtle. thanks for your help!

Comment: Wow OK, glad that worked.  I added that as an answer, you can upvote/accept it if you'd like :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try turning off notifications in the system Messages app, if you can? Or changing them to the sound you want.